# Poem of the ball

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

Your ball is not it
It is not yours
We love bras
Bras are nothing
Bras define who we
Are and shows it
Are not who we
Bras are not French
It can be used on spas
Gems, but not French

**What cup size do we talk about?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What cup size? How about one the size of:

> the **WORLD**! i.e. the men's football **World Cup**.

Since:

> Each line of the poem begins and ends with a word containing a substring which starts the name of each winner of the competition, in order (with one homophone and one missing entry):
>
>  Yo**ur** (**Ur**uguay 1930) ball is not **it** (**It**aly 1934)
>  **It** (**It**aly 1938) is not yo**ur**s (**Ur**uguay 1950)
>  **We** (**We**st Germany 1954) love **bra**s (**Bra**zil 1958)
>  **Bra**s (**Bra**zil 1962) are noth**ing** (**Eng**land 1966 - alternatively, ar**e n**othing spans two words with 'en')
>  **Bra**s (**Bra**zil 1970) define who **we** (**We**st Germany 1974)
>  **Ar**e (**Ar**gentina 1978) and shows **it** (**It**aly 1982)
>  **Ar**e (**Ar**gentina 1986) not who **we** (**We**st Germany 1990)
>  **Bra**s (**Bra**zil 1994) are not **Fr**ench (**Fr**ance 1998)
>  **It** (**It**aly 2006) can be used on **spa**s (**Spa**in 2010)
>  **Ge**ms (**Ge**rmany 2014), but not **Fr**ench (**Fr**ance 2018)
>
>  Only Brazil in 2002 is missing from this list. This also explains the relevance of 'ball' in the title.

Comment: Nice. Was that to easy?

Comment: I just happen to be a huge fan of the sport :) To someone like me it was almost an instant spot (largely thanks to the repetition of 'Bras' throughout - if you watch it on TV you see a 3-letter abbreviation for that country up by the score!) but it had other views before I got to it, so presumably to others it was more of a headscratcher :)